# Loading Dynamic Package Under a Windows Service In Delphi Alexandria

Tags: windows, delphi, service, package

I built a Windows Service Application where load a dynamic Delphi package (my own package) and when I invoke some method using the code below, I receive a generic AV message. If I take the `exports` clause off (in my own package), it works perfectly. Executing the same procedure in a console application still run perfectly.
I suspect it must be some detail regarding Windows Service applications.

My code:

```
var 
  MyProc: procedure(); 
begin 
  @MyProc := GetProcAddress(nHandle, 'MyMethod');
  if Assigned(MyProc) then
    MyProc();
end;
```

Important: I am using all Delphi resources (Package, Windows Service)

I tried to declare the procedure using `stdcall` instruction but no effect.

Comment: Show a complete example that includes the dynamic loading and where files are. Also keep in mind services run in their own contexts so might not find required libraries/files in the same locations as when running as regular program.

Comment: How is `MyMethod` implemented, exactly? How is `nHandle` being loaded, exactly? Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue in action.

Comment: Thank you to your awswer. Keeping more attention in the problem, I found a detail that solv my problem. In this case I need to share methods from static package to dynamic package and I forgot to check the Link With Runtime Package in project options. After that works perfectly. Regards Brian and Remy ;)